# Java EE test strategy

Tags: unit-testing, authentication, jakarta-ee, testing

Java EE is a new world for me, my experiences are on embedded systems, but I started a new job and I would like to know if there is a test process to follow for web applications based on Java EE. Which test strategy is usually adopted in this field?

- Basic Unit test
- Functional test
- Integration test
- System test, stress test, load test,....

....
and which is the scope of each test phase for web development? As server code and client code are both involved I don't know which is the best approach in this field. Also, several machines are involved: DB, buisness tier, presentation tier, load balancers, authentication with CAS, Active Directory,...

Which is the best test environment for each phases? When using the production CAS authentication, ...

Links, books, simple explanation or other kind of address is well appreciated.

Comment: quick side note it should be JEE, as J2EE is 6 years old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, whatever you plan to do as testing, take care of your build process (a good starting point is maven as build tool)

Junit (or testng) is almost good for everything (due to its simplicity)

Unit test:
For mock, I would prefer Mockito to jmock or easymock.

Acceptance test:
Regarding UI testing selenium is fine for web application (give a look at PageObject pattern if you plan to do a lot of UI testing).
For other interface testing (such as webservice), soapui is a nice starting point.

Integration testing:
You will face the middle ware problem, mainly solved in java by a container. Now it becomes fun :) If you run in "real" JEE, then it depends if it's prior to JEE6 or not as from JEE6 you have an embedded container (which really ease the testing). Otherwise, go for a dependency injection framework (Spring, Guice, ...).

Other hints for integration or acceptance testing:

- you will may be need to mock some interface (give a look to MOCO to mock external service based on HTTP).
- also think about some embedded servlet container (Jetty) to ease web the testing.
- configuration and provisioning can be a problem too. ex.: for the DB you can automate this with "flyway" or "liquibase"
- DB testing you have two approach: resetting data after each test (see DBUnit) or in transaction testing (see Spring test for an example)

Answer (score 1):

The best test framework is Junit -for unit tests, in my opinion. 
    http://www.junit.org/
    -for mocking objects, which you will need a lot, like to mock the database, mock services and other object in j2ee environment to be able to test in isolation .use http://www.jmock.org/ , http://code.google.com/p/mockito/, http://www.easymock.org/
    -for acceptance and functional testing there is selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ this framework enables you to automate your tests. 
    I Advice you to read this books about testing in general and testing in j2ee evironment in particular.

```
http://www.manning.com/rainsberger/ 
http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-By-Example/dp/0321146530
http://manning.com/massol/ 
http://manning.com/koskela/
```